# $compile in Angular 1.5 component throws $.watch is not a function error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, components

I am migrating a `directive` to `component` structure, and everything was going fine - except I had a dynamic template that I'm compiling on the fly. Was working fine except when I try to pass `ctrl` into the $compile:

I changed:

```
$compile($element.contents())($scope);
```

which was working - to:

```
$compile($element.contents())(ctrl);
```

And now I'm getting this error:

```
child-component.component.js:76 TypeError: b.$watch is not a function
    at Object.link (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:302:155)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:16:56
    at ja (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:81:35)
    at m (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:66:274)
    at g (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:58:481)
    at g (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:58:498)
    at g (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:58:498)
    at g (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:58:498)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:58:119
    at http://localhost:3000/js/components/component-group/child-component.component.js:76:54
```

Here is an example of an element with some ctrl in it as I suspect the issue is with the binding.

```
<div class="box" ng-class="{selected:ctrl.selected == 1}" ng-show="ctrl.selected">
```

Here is my component declaration:

```
var childComponent = {
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    require: 'parentComponent',
    bindings: {
        attrone: '<',
        attrtwo: '<'
    },
    controller: childComponentController
};

function childComponentController(SomeFactory, $rootScope, $compile, $timeout, $element, $scope) {
etc...
```

What am I doing wrong with the migration?

Comment: Please provide your component declaration. Or at least the basic structure. There are a few things that need to be amended when converting directives to components. This will make it easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @zilj thanks! I just added my declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would tidy up your component to iron out any syntax issues first.

component:

```
var childComponent = {
  require: {
    parent: '^parentComponent'
  },
  bindings: {
    attrOne: '<',
    attrTwo: '<'
  },
  controller: function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('Parent:', vm.parent);
    }
  }
};
```

- assign the parent to the controller with object syntax
- Use a '^' to search for the parent controller on the same level or higher.
- camelcase your binding properties
- Update view to use native `$ctrl` namespace

View:

```
<div class="box" ng-class="{ 'selected': $ctrl.selected === 1 }" ng-show="$ctrl.selected">
```

I also believe that your $compile should not have changed. $compile should use $scope. Try setting it back to `$compile($element.contents())($scope);`

If you are able to replicate in a codepen or similar I'll be happy to get it working for you with a report on the issue.